# Problems with Curity installlation

Tags: curity

After installing Curity with Docker, I was asked to enter the code below into the command prompt.

> docker run -it -e PASSWORD=<ADMIN_PASSWORD> -p 6749:6749 -p 8443:8443 curity.azurecr.io/curity/idsvr

The error message I get is:

> The system cannot find the file specified.

Any thoughts?

Mike

see above see above

Answer (score 1):

The <ADMIN_PASSWORD> is a placeholder so give it a value like this:

```bash
docker pull curity.azurecr.io/curity/idsvr
docker run -it -e PASSWORD=Mys3cret -p 6749:6749 -p 8443:8443 curity.azurecr.io/curity/idsvr
```

Then login to the Admin UI with these details:

```
URL: https://localhost:6749/admin
User: admin
Password: Mys3cret
```

Then run the basic setup wizard. Accept all default options and upload a license file when prompted. You will then be able to locate the OAuth related endpoints at the discovery endpoint. The initial setup on a development computer starts with plain HTTP endpoints to avoid SSL trust issues when getting started:

```
http://localhost:8443/oauth/v2/oauth-anonymous/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

Next follow [steps 3 and 4](https://curity.io/resources/learn/username-password-authenticator/) from the getting started documentation, to get some flows up and running.